# how to trigger validation for both the values of picklist,its only work for 1st value

Tags: validation, validation-rule

```
AND(ISNEW(),
    IF(OR(TEXT(StageName)= "10% Opportunity Identified",
    TEXT(StageName)="20% - Opportunity qualified    "),
    FALSE,TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation rule should be

`AND(
ISNEW(),
AND(TEXT(StageName) != "10% Opportunity Identified", TEXT(StageName) !="20% - Opportunity qualified")
)`

Comment: by using above,none of the values work for me,its give error everytime when selecting,

Comment: You need to fire the validation rule when these values are not selected?

Comment: yes,we need to fire the validation rule when these values are not selected

Comment: Edited the rule. Try this. Do verify the picklist values also for typos